# Why do imagesc and pcolor plots produce different output? Possible bug in MATLAB R2015a

Tags: matlab, plot

From the [MATLAB R2015a documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html), the functions `pcolor`, `image` and `imagesc` are expected to produce nearly the same output, being the only "practical" difference that `pcolor` outputs surfaces viewed from above while `image` and `imagesc` uses the color matrix to color pixels, instead of edges and faces.

However, my example below shows a case in which `imagesc` differs from `pcolor`. The [example data can be downloaded](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9tpa012s3oryl3r/testData.zip?dl=0) (I am sorry that it is 11MB large) from my dropbox.

```
%% different output
clearvars
close all
d = importdata('testData.dat');
% x,y,c below are my real data, instead of d
x = reshape(d(:,1), 2170, 2616);
y = reshape(d(:,2), 2170, 2616);
c = reshape(d(:,3), 2170, 2616);
h=pcolor(x,y,c)
set(h,'EdgeColor', 'none')
figure
imagesc(x(:),y(:),c)
axis xy
```

The output figures are:

- **`pcolor` output for testData.dat**
  [image: Output of pcolor function for testData.dat]
- **`imagesc` output for testData.dat**
  [image: Output of imagesc function for testData.dat]

All other data I tried to plot with either functions produced the same output. For instance, take the following:

```
%% equal output
[x,y]=meshgrid(linspace(0,10,1000),linspace(0,5,600));
c = zeros(size(x));
c(100:500,700:800) = 1; % create a rectangle
h=pcolor(x,y,c)
set(h,'EdgeColor', 'none')
figure
imagesc(x(:),y(:),c)
axis xy
```

which produces:

- **`pcolor` and `imagesc` outputs for generated data**
  [image: Output of both pcolor and imagesc functions for generated data]

### Trying to come up with a solution

Now, the solution for `testData.dat` is to plot the transpose of `c`, like `imagesc(x(:),y(:),c');axis xy` which then produces exactly the same output as `pcolor`.

The problem is that if I do plot the transpose for the generated data in the second example, I end up getting the rotated rectangle:

- **`imagesc` output for transpose of `c` in generated data**
  [image: Output of imagesc for transpose of generated data]

So the point is I think this is really a bug and I have no idea why this problem is happening. Although I have a solution for my `testData.dat` particular case, the problem I face is not reproduced with any other set of data that I have already tested (which is all the other data I have plotted in the same figure but I did not show here because it is 2GB data).

Do you have any hint about this one?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your data is not set up the same in both cases. In your rectangle plot, `x` and `y` are created using `meshgrid`, but the `x` and `y` from `testData.dat` are not in the same format. This might be a cause of difference between the to examples. Try just `pcolor(c)` and `imagesc(c);axis xy`.

Comment: yes, I was also suspecting of that... If I use both functions only with `c`, the output is the same. Although I didn't generate `x` and `y` using `meshplot`, I tried to take care in order to keep it equal. It seems I didn't took care enough...

Comment: Also, if I use `x = x'`,`y=y'` and `c=c'` and then call `imagesc(x(:),y(:),c);axis xy` it works fine

Comment: imagesc(x,y,C) does not use the x- and y-vectors as you would expect. The x- and y-data basically sets the x- and y- labels. They do not even need to be the same dimension as C. Try this: `imagesc(1:7,1:9,rand(100))` as an example of what I mean. The pcolor view is transposed, because it actually uses the x and y to position the image.

Comment: yes, @julietKiloRomeo, although it is very counter-intuitive... One would expect that each element `c(i)` in `c` matrix would be linked to each pair `x(i),y(i)` from vectors `x,y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `pcolor` and `imagesc` will produce the same behavior if you take the transpose of `testData.dat`'s `x`, `y` and `c`:

```
clearvars
close all
d = importdata('testData.dat');
% x,y,c below are my real data, instead of d
x = reshape(d(:,1), 2170, 2616);
y = reshape(d(:,2), 2170, 2616);
c = reshape(d(:,3), 2170, 2616);
x = x'; y = y'; c = c'; % add this line to produce the same output
h=pcolor(x,y,c)
set(h,'EdgeColor', 'none')
figure
imagesc(x(:),y(:),c)
axis xy
```

This issue happens because, as pointed out in the comments by @David and @julietKiloRomeo, `imagesc` deals with vectors `x` and `y` separately from `c`, using the latter to color the axes' pixels whereas `x` and `y` are used to label the axes.

As far as I can tell, this behavior of `imagesc` is very counter-intuitive, mainly considering what's stated in the Documentation pointed in the question: if `imagesc` and `pcolor` were suppose to produce similar outputs, `imagesc` should use `x` and `y` vectors as coordinates to be painted by `c` matrix.